# Should I restart the instance after adjusting Memory Allocation and MAXDOP?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

As far as I know adjusting **Maximum server memory** and **Max Degree of Parallelism** does not require the instance to be restarted. Will new settings always come into effect without restart?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of those server configuration options do **not** require a restart of the database engine.  Running `RECONFIGURE` will be sufficient in this case.

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
go
reconfigure
go

exec sp_configure 'max server memory', 12288
go
exec sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 4
go

reconfigure
go

-- the new configuration has taken effect
```

Please see [BOL for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189631).

Comment: Note that the reconfigure will still do things to your instance that you might only expect during a restart, e.g. blow away the plan cache. So some queries might feel like the service was restarted. :-)